# Quick search to find active urls

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I'm trying to use cURL to find active rediractions and save results to file. I know the url is active, when it redirects at least once to specific website. So I came up with:

```
if (( $( curl -I -L https://mywebpage.com/id=00001&somehashnumber&si=0 | grep -c "/something/" ) > 1 )) ; then echo https://mywebpage.com/id=00001&somehashnumber&si=0 | grep -o -P 'id=.{0,5}' >> id.txt; else echo 404; fi
```

And it works, but how to modify it to check id range from 00001 to 99999?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll want to wrap the whole operation in a for loop and use a formatted sequence to print the ids you'd like to test. without know too much about the task at hand i would write something like this to test the ids

$ for i in $(seq -f "%06g" 1 100000); do curl --silent "example.com/id=$i" --write-out "$i %{response_code}\n" --output /dev/null; done

Comment: Thx, i figured it out, but your solution is much cleaner.